# Does default Zxing.Net.Mobile overlay contain a flash/torch button?

Tags: win-universal-app, zxing, torch, flashlight

I am using the Zxing.Net.Mobile package within my Windows 10 universal app. I use the Default overlay, which is quite nice in my eyes. Now I want to add Flash/Torch funtionality to my application. I only found Solutions defining a new customn overlay. Is it not possible to activate a Torch button in the default overlay? I found a scanner.FlashButtonText Definition, so i think a flashbutton should somehow be activatable and i just dont know the Name of this Parameter. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

my Code Looks like this:

```
            var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                AutoRotate = false,
                TryHarder = true,
                PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>
                {
                    ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_8, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_13, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.UPC_A, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.UPC_E
                }
            };


            var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.Dispatcher);

            scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
            scanner.RootFrame = MyFrame;
            scanner.TopText = "Halte die Kamera vor den Barcode";
            scanner.BottomText = "Die Kamera scannt den Barcode automatisch";
            scanner.FlashButtonText = "activate Torch";


            var result = await scanner.Scan(options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `MobileBarcodeScanner` has a `FlashButtonText` property, but according to [ZXing.Net.Mobile's source code](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile), Flash/Torch function is not supported in the default overlay by now.

The default overlay is set by [ZXingScannerControl](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/ZXingScannerControl.xaml) and if we look at its source code, we will find it does have a button named *"buttonToggleFlash"*. However this button is invisible and there is no property can control its visibility.

[source code](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/ZXingScannerControl.xaml#L40-L42):

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" Height="80">
    <Button x:Name="buttonToggleFlash" Click="buttonToggleFlash_Click">Flash</Button>
</Border>
```

So to support Flash/Torch function, you need a customn overlay. Or you can edit the source code and rebuild ZXing.Net.Mobile for your purpose.